# Android stretch background image programmatically

Tags: android, image, background

I'm using an image downloaded from internet as background of one of my activities. But my problem is that I want to stretch the image programmatically so it can fit in any resolution. The code which I'm using to set the image as background to my RelativeLayout is this :

```
    BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    options.inTempStorage = new byte[4*1024];

    Bitmap ops = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path, options);
    BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(ops);
    layoutBG.setBackgroundDrawable(bitmapDrawable);
```

So any ideas how can I set the image to stretch?

Comment: How does it look for you now? Where does layoutBG come from? Do you get it from a layout XML? Normally, if you set a background to a view, it is stretched to the size of the view. Maybe you need to make sure that the view covers the whole screen?

Comment: I get the layout from xml file and I set it's params to `fill_parent`, but the background is not stretched in height.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check your `xml` file for any `paddings` or `margins`, because if you have margins in your `RelativeLayout` the image won't stretch the whole layout.

Comment: actually i just saw that i had `marginBottom`. Thanks for answer!